# In JavaScript ES6, why can you do `const foo = { };` and then change the object anyway you want?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, constants

Is it true that in JavaScript ES6, you can

```
const foo = {};
```

and then still change the object in anyway you want?

Such as

```
foo.bar = 1;
foo.bar++;
delete foo.bar;
```

because it is a "constant" (`const`) meaning that the ***reference*** to this object can never change, but what is inside of this object (all the properties or methods (which are also properties)) can change in any way?

Comment: You are absolutely right.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the only real answer is "Yes." If you understand the behavior, you probably don't need to ask a question about it.

Comment: Is it true you didn't even read the documentation, which clearly describes this behavior, and you're only mining rep?

Comment: you might find [Object.freeze()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze) interesting

Comment: I actually am viewing an online course, and it does `const` in this fashion, and the instructor immediately change the object without explanation, and was surprising to me... and I thought, could it be that the reference doesn't change, but the properties can change in any way, hence the question

Comment: Rephrase your question to "How come" to avoid it being closed.

Comment: OP, you might want to mark one of the provided answers as **accepted**.

Answer (score 1):

> The const declaration creates a read-only reference to a value. It
>   does not mean the value it holds is immutable, just that the variable
>   identifier cannot be reassigned. For instance, in case the content is
>   an object, this means the object itself can still be altered.

[More on Const at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const)

ES6 const does not indicate that a value is ‘constant’ or immutable. A const value can definitely change. The only thing that’s immutable here is the binding.

Comment: sort of like, if `foo` points to the house at "123 Cherry Street, ABC City, CA, USA", then the `foo` pointing to this address can never change, but the content inside the house can change in any way

Comment: I am not getting your example very well, consider this. `foo` points to a Bag, and can only point to that bag, but contents of bag can change in any way.

Comment: how come you can see it pointing to a bag but not to a house?

Comment: @太極者無極而生 I like the bag! Just kidding, now I see both examples looks same. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in ES6 you can **change** the Object properties and assign any value you want even if you are using

> const

[const at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const)